# While installing hadoop why do we turn iptables off?

Tags: hadoop

Why do we turn off iptables and Disable selinux.
Is there a workaround for this as it may cause security flaws?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Hadoop clusters are built with "high walls". This basically means secure the outside of the cluster from random people getting in with iptables et al. But then once you are logged in you are trusted and anything goes. This usually isn't that hard if your Hadoop cluster data nodes are on a separate network, which is the norm for larger clusters. Security can impact performance, potentially cause things to break, and other bad things, so if you don't need it, don't use it.

This doesn't work for everyone, though. Either because of untrusted users or regulatory requirements. Authentication and authorization are challenging to solve in a distributed system like Hadoop and I'd end up writing a book on the subject to answer your question. I recommend taking a look at the new book Hadoop Security to help you with some of this http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033332.do .

Answer (score 0):

As perspective, we know Hadoop have it's own firewall system, so if in case don't want to be depend on underlying firewall.

Also we can say this underlying firewall takes part in communication every time, which is not necessary as you already have strong firewall

One more reason can be added that some communication error will come and we have to manage or resolve them, so rather than it's better to be disable.